# about Usage of Completer in Dart

Tags: dart-async

As a new in Dart, not easy to understand Completer.
Especially this part in Dart Library doc,

```
    class AsyncOperation {
      final Completer _completer = new Completer();

      Future<T> doOperation() {
             _startOperation();
             return _completer.future; // Send future object back to client.
      }

     // Something calls this when the value is ready.
      void _finishOperation(T result) {
            _completer.complete(result);
      }

     // If something goes wrong, call this.
      void _errorHappened(error) {
            _completer.completeError(error);
      }
  }
```

codes above mentioned on Dart doc.

I am wondering :

(1) future instance returned from Completer.future doesn't have real work to be proceed asynchronously.
where can i write the working to be executed asynchronously ?

I think this is simple part to someone.
I hope your help. thanks to you who read .